# How do you guys (network) render animation locally?

Tags: rendering, network

This question may sound odd, but after after two days of research I´m not really more enlightened on this issue:
How do you guys render your animation frames using different machines locally? The rendermanager in 2.79 seems to be very basic to me (manually starting each scene on every client etc.). This wont help me if I render a bunch of scenes and sub-scenes over night/weekend (which I often do).

Flamenco.io seemed a possible solution but is not very communicative about how to run a farm locally. Checked some other addons but they were either discontinued or did not have the features as described above.

So my question is: how do you render your animations in your local renderfarm?
What´s your pipeline?

Thanx!

Sigmund

Comment: Well, I don't render animations locally, but I do is SheepIt Render Farm for most of my heavy-scale rendering.

Comment: Thank you, Samino. I also stumbled upon SheepIt, but sadly a cloud renderer is not what I am looking for. A: I want to use my local PCs B: my customers would not be amused when parts of our projects appear somewhere else (which I guess could happen when I sendi my data to other peoples PC for rendering).